# Do I need Playstation Plus to play Splitscreen?

Tags: playstation-plus, star-wars-battlefront-2015

Can I play Star Wars Battlefront (2015) without having Playstation Plus? What about Splitscreen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "training mode" available for single-player offline play. Splitscreen is also available offline. You don't need PS Plus for either. You only need PS Plus to play online.